# How to treat a float as an integer bit level in AssemblyScript

Tags: assemblyscript

I need to implement some C code blow:

```c
float number = 1.5f
long i = * ( long * ) &number;
```

It is not about to convert the **value** from float into integer.
This data need to be modified bit level.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `reinterpret` built-in function:

```
let num32: f32 = 1.5
let num64: f64 = 2.5

let uint32 = reinterpret<u32>(num32);
// uint32 <- 0x3fc00000
let uint64 = reinterpret<u64>(num64);
// uint64 <- 0x4004000000000000
```